# Where can I find a free JScript editor  extension for VS 2010 Express?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, visual-studio-express, visual-studio-extensions

It's hard to see a structure of a .js file in VS 2010 Express, but the [JScript Editor Extensions](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/872d27ee-38c7-4a97-98dc-0d8a431cc2ed) are only for VS 2010. It will not work on VS 2010 Express.

Alternatively, if there is not free extension for VS 2010 Express, is there a free standalone piece of software that can do it?

Comment: That's correct. Extensions are mostly unsupported in the Express version. The real answer is to upgrade to the Professional version or higher. Otherwise, you will have to find a third-party piece of software. Helping you to choose one of many such editors is off-topic for this site, as per the [FAQ].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extensions support for Visual Studio 2010 Express is really limited and most of extensions from gallery will not install so you will have to use external javascript editor if you are not satisfied with the one included in visual studio. There are many options, starting from powerful text editors like Notepad++ (if you just want something to help you with your existing IDE) to complete IDEs like Netbeans or Eclipse and online solutions like Cloud9. Take a look at [this](http://www.js-monkey.com/archive/javascript-newsletter-4.html) list or check [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/925219/best-javascript-editor-or-ide-with-intellisense-and-debugging-possibly)